# if by mistake a user overwrote a keyword, for example, range

Tags: python

```
for range in ranges:
    print(range)
```

I have used the above code by mistake overwrote `range` keyword - Is there any way to retrieve this keyword?

Comment: Change the name of your variable to something else than `range`...

Answer (score 1):

You can get it from the `builtins` module:

```
import builtins
range = builtins.range
```

Or if you're using Python 2.7 or earlier:

```
import __builtin__
range = __builtin__.range
```

Comment: this works 
do i need to do this whenver i like to use range

Comment: Do this just in case you overwrite a keyword by mistake in a Python shell, but don't do it intentionally in your actual code as it can easily make your code hard to debug and cause confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Issue a

```
del range
```

and you'll have your `range` back.